# How to enable TLS 1.2 in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, openssl

How do I enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 for SSL connections in my Ubuntu 12.04 server? I am using the following version of nginx and openssl library.

```
$ ./nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.2.3

$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
built on: Tue Jun  4 07:26:06 UTC 2013
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: cc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -DOPENSSL_NO_TLS1_2_CLIENT -DOPENSSL_MAX_TLS1_2_CIPHER_LENGTH=50 -DMD32_REG_T=int -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
```

Comment: You found anything yet?

Comment: Did you resolve this? The nginx version your are using is very old. You may find the SSL configuration in this [Ars Technica article](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2012/11/securing-your-web-server-with-ssltls/) useful.

Answer (score 16):

First you need to activate SSL/TLS in your `nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.org;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/example.org.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example.org.key;
```

The two `listen` lines enable SSL at your IPv4 and IPv6 connection. If you have no IPv6 you might leave out the second `listen` line.

I assume that your server certificate is in `/etc/ssl`. If you use another path, you'd change the last two lines.

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
```

This enables different TLS versions. All current browsers are able to use TLS1.2. For older browsers I wrote a [small howto enable secure settings](http://kubieziel.de/blog/archives/1564-Using-SSL-securely-in-your-browser.html).

```
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

The first line sets the ciphers which your nignx should use. The second line prefers the cipher suites on the server (and not the client) side. So you can use strong(er) ciphers.

If you're done, your nginx should use TLS1.2. If you'd like, you can [add](https://ssl-stats.hacked.jp/add) your site to a [TLS1.2 hall of fame](https://ssl-stats.hacked.jp/halloffame) and be proud. ;)

However there are several methods to improve the settings. I follow [this german guide for secure nginx configuration](https://sherbers.de/howto/nginx/).

Comment: Ubuntu 12 disables TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 for interop reasons. I think they recently enabled TLS 1.1, but I believe TLS 1.2 is still lacking. See [OpenSSL downlevel version is 1.0.0, and does not support TLS 1.2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/1256576).

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous security advisories that have been addressed in subsequent versions of nginx.  If you're still (6 months stale post?) in this situation, seriously consider upgrading; TLS settings won't matter if the web server itself is insecure.  See http://nginx.org/en/security_advisories.html for details.

If, for some reason you MUST run this version of nginx, the information available on enabling strong cipher suites with nginx (or Apache) here will probably help: https://community.qualys.com/blogs/securitylabs/2013/08/05/configuring-apache-nginx-and-openssl-for-forward-secrecy

Answer (score 0):

> How do I enable TLS 1.1 and 1.2 for SSL connections in my Ubuntu 12.04 server?

I believe there are three choices.

First, do nothing and use Ubuntu 12's version of OpenSSL. I believe TLS 1.1 is now supported, but you still won't have TLS 1.2.

Second, build and maintain your own [PPA](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/ppa/). There are some instructions for doing so at [Override Distro Package with Custom Package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395280/override-distro-package-with-custom-package) For completeness, there are no existing [Personal Package Archives for Ubuntu and OpenSSL](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=openssl) that offer the full protocols.

Third is upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu, like Ubuntu 14. I'm trying to determine if Ubuntu 14 enables them all at the moment. See [Ubuntu 14, OpenSSL, and TLS Protocols?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/440139/ubuntu-14-openssl-and-tls-protocols).